# write for loop xml parsing java

Tags: xml, for-loop, xml-parsing

Can someone help me how can i write a for loop to iterate over all these zones node and get the text of only class lead?

```
<zones count="13">
                    <zone type="RECT" flags="4099" class="Headline" num="1">
                        <zrect unit="pix">0,1097,2173,1303</zrect>
                        <ztext type="XML" textformat="XML">
                            <REGION>
                                <PARAGRAPH>
                                    <LINE>
                                        <WORD Rect="27,933,272,1067">ma</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="325,933,820,1096">ekdum</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="877,933,982,1065">gyani</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="1040,933,1829,1096">chu</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                    </LINE>
                                </PARAGRAPH>
                            </REGION>
                        </ztext>
                        <source/>
                    </zone>
                    <zone type="RECT" flags="4099" class="Author" num="2">
                        <zrect unit="pix">0,1326,324,1372</zrect>
                        <ztext type="XML" textformat="XML">
                            <REGION>
                                <PARAGRAPH>
                                    <LINE>
                                        <WORD Rect="4,1126,44,1158">By</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="54,1126,131,1151">Sano</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="145,1126,272,1151">shrest</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                    </LINE>
                                </PARAGRAPH>
                            </REGION>
                        </ztext>
                        <source/>
                    </zone>
                    <zone type="RECT" flags="4099" class="Lead" num="3">
                        <zrect unit="pix">0,1384,475,1584</zrect>
                        <ztext type="XML" textformat="XML">
                            <REGION>
                                <PARAGRAPH>
                                    <LINE>
                                        <WORD Rect="5,1174,42,1192">Dherai</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="55,1178,118,1198">years</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="130,1178,166,1192">dekhin</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="179,1174,263,1192">gadi</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="277,1174,331,1192">banaune</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="344,1174,399,1192">manche</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                    </LINE>
                                    <LINE>
                                        <WORD Rect="4,1203,91,1226">haru</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="115,1203,147,1221">mehanat</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="172,1207,218,1221">gardai</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="241,1203,399,1226">chan</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                    </LINE>
                                    <LINE>
                                        <WORD Rect="3,1236,63,1255">ramro</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="80,1233,102,1250">gadi</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="119,1231,214,1255">nirman</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="232,1231,323,1254">garna</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="341,1236,400,1250">lai</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                    </LINE>
                                </PARAGRAPH>
                            </REGION>
                        </ztext>
                        <source/>
                    </zone>
                    <zone type="RECT" flags="4099" class="Paragraph" num="4">
                        <zrect unit="pix">0,1596,478,2249</zrect>
                        <ztext type="XML" textformat="XML">
                            <REGION>
                                <PARAGRAPH>
                                    <LINE>
                                        <WORD Rect="28,1352,74,1366">Ramro</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="82,1356,114,1366">gadi</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="122,1356,151,1369">are,</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="158,1352,179,1366">for</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="186,1356,196,1366">a</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="202,1352,254,1369">variety</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="262,1352,274,1366">of</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="283,1356,348,1368">reasons,</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                        <WORD Rect="356,1352,400,1369">ramro</WORD>
                                        <BLANK/>
                                    </LINE>
                                </PARAGRAPH>
                            </REGION>
                        </ztext>
                        <source/>
                    </zone>
```

I was able to get the text of all the zones but not particularly with the attribute class = "Lead"

Comment: What are you using to parse the xml?

Comment: i am using xpath. however i cannot give the position of the node while the structure will change for different xml files. i.e. here the class Lead is in num=3 but in other xml the class Lead can be in num=1.

Comment: According to w3schools, if you use `//zone[@class='Lead']`, you will get all the zones with class Lead. Then you can loop them to get the text you need.

Answer (score 0):

Example from W3 Schools.
Source: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

This is the xml:

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web" cover="paperback">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

And the Javascript function that will extract the nodes you wish. Notice that we are using `//book[@category='web']` to get all the nodes with that **attribute=value** pair. Similarly, you can do `//zone[@class='Lead']`.

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function showResult(xml) {
    var txt = "";
    path = "//book[@category='web']/title";
    if (xml.evaluate) {
        var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result = nodes.iterateNext();
        while (result) {
            txt += result.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            result = nodes.iterateNext();
        } 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```